# Returning a class from a constexpr function requires virtual keyword with g++

Tags: c++, g++, c++14, constexpr, g++4.9

Hi the following program works with g++ 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) but the `virtual` keyword is required for the function `get` :

```
//g++ -std=c++14 test.cpp
//test.cpp

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
constexpr auto create() {
  class test {
  public:
    int i;
    virtual int get(){
      return 123;
    }
  } r;
  return r;
}

auto v = create<int>();

int main(void){
  cout<<v.get()<<endl;
}
```

If I omit the `virtual` keyword, I get the following error :

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘constexpr auto create() [with T = int]’:
test.cpp:18:22:   required from here
test.cpp:16:1: error: body of constexpr function ‘constexpr auto create() [with T = int]’ not a return-statement
 }
 ^
```

How can I get the code above to work (with g++) without having to use the `virtual` keyword?

Comment: Program compiles fine with a [recent version of g++](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/MYiV0wciN8hWmhAM). The relaxed C++14 constexpr function rules are implemented in gcc >= 5, see https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html Prior to those, you couldn't declare a class within a constexpr function. The lack of a diagnostic when `get` is `virtual` is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Classes defined inside a function cannot be accessed outside the function.
My suggestion are: declare `test` outside the function and add `const` qualifier to `get` function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

  class test {
  public:
    int i;
    int get() const {
      return 123;
    }
  };

template<typename T>
constexpr test create() {
  return test();
}

auto v = create<int>();

int main(void){
  cout<<v.get()<<endl;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately this is not how I want to do things for my particular work case.

Comment: *"Classes defined inside a function cannot be accessed outside the function."* This is incorrect since C++14's return type deduction (or C++11's relaxed return type deduction for lambdas).

Comment: @Andrey Nasonov See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806835/how-to-specify-type-of-a-constexpr-function-returning-a-class-without-resorting?noredirect=1#comment53450804_32806835 for a more detailed explanation of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Is this supported by g++ 4.9.2?