# How to specify type of a constexpr function returning a class (without resorting to auto keyword)

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr, clang++, g++4.9

Basically in below I want to see if I can get around having to use `auto` keyword

Suppose that we have the following piece of code [works with g++ 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) & clang version 3.6.0] :

```
//g++ -std=c++14 test.cpp
//test.cpp

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
constexpr auto create() {
  class test {
  public:
    int i;
    virtual int get(){
      return 123;
    }
  } r;
  return r;
}

auto v = create<int>();

int main(void){
  cout<<v.get()<<endl;
}
```

How can I specify the type of `v` rather than using the 
`auto` keyword at its point of declaration/definition? I tried `create<int>::test v = create<int>();` but this does not work.

p.s.

1)this is different from the question that I was asking at [Returning a class from a constexpr function requires virtual keyword with g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806405/returning-a-class-from-a-constexpr-function-requires-virtual-keyword-with-g) even through the code is the same

2)I do **not** want to define the class outside the function.

Comment: You make your class function-local and then ask how to access it from outside the function. Even if you can (and you can, in this case), the question isn't a sensical one. If you want your class to be accessible from outside the function, you shouldn't make it function-local...

Comment: @hvd : `If you want your class to be accessible from outside the function` It clearly is **already** accessible outside the function.

Comment: Given that I specifically included a note on that, I don't see why you feel the need to remind me, I am clearly already aware of it. The relevant part in that sentence is the part that follows what you quoted: so stop making it function-local. You don't give any reason in your question why you would want to keep it function-local, only *that* you want to.

Comment: @hvd `You don't give any reason in your question why you would want to keep it function-local, only that you want to` : Basically I am trying to emulate the way that standard ml functors work in c++.  You can do a lot specifying everything via template parameters, but then eventually you end up having too many template parameters. I am trying to use `constexpr` functions to **transform** one template class into another, and this allows me to reduce the number of template parameters I need for the resulting class. See http://jozefg.bitbucket.org/posts/2015-01-08-modules.html for SML functors

Comment: @hvd : therefore I have to define the class **inside** the `constexpr` function. If I define the template function outside the `constexpr` function, I will have to specify the extra template parameters, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: `create<int>::test` (if it were valid) uses exactly as many template arguments as a `createhelper<int>` global class, and exactly as many as `decltype(create<int>())` too. So it doesn't appear to me as if you achieve your goal of making your classes have fewer template parameters. But I should note that I don't know Haskell and don't completely understand what's in your link, so I may just be missing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual type is hidden as it's local inside the function, so you can't explicitly use it. You should however be able to use `decltype` as in

```
decltype(create<int>()) v = create<int>();
```

I fail to see a reason to do like this though, when `auto` works.

Comment: That's brilliant thanks. I am fine with `auto` but I just wanted to see if I could explicitly specify its type.